# How can we customize the font size of the window-number in `ace-window` mode?

Tags: window, fonts, customize

The font face of the window labels in ace window seem to have the same size as that of the text in the buffer, which is in general too small for me to allow for quick visual parsing.

I was hoping that there would be a separate font face for the numbers in ace-window, but I could not find it in the options in `M-x customize-faces`.

The source code in `ace-window.el` has a function called [`aw--face-rel-height`](https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window/blob/77115afc1b0b9f633084cf7479c767988106c196/ace-window.el#L879), which if I guess correctly should control the face height, but from what I understand this function is not meant to be used directly.

So, what is the intended way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the proper face to change: `aw-leading-char-face`.